# Colour intensity is changing when stacking numpy image arrays

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I am loading an image from [here](https://github.com/Jimut123/simply_junk/blob/main/image.nii.gz?raw=true), which is saved as .nii.gz. The image opens fine (with a dimension of (497x497)), and when displayed using matplotlib, it shows with correct intensities, as shown below:

[image: kidney image 1]

When we are trying to make it a 3 channel image, by stacking the numpy array, and after plotting it, the intensity changes, as shown below:

[image: kidney image 2]

Any idea how to resolve this? The minimal code to reproduce the problem in google colaboratory is present here:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
import skimage.io as io
from nibabel import nifti1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

! wget "https://github.com/Jimut123/simply_junk/blob/main/image.nii.gz?raw=true" -O image.nii.gz

image_file_name = "image.nii.gz"
print(image_file_name)
epi_img = nib.load(image_file_name)
epi_img_data = epi_img.get_fdata()
epi_img_data = epi_img_data/epi_img_data.max()
# epi_img_data = epi_img_data[..., np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(epi_img_data)
plt.show()

total_mask = np.stack((epi_img_data,)*3, axis=-1)
plt.imshow(total_mask,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Like for example this is a 3-channel image (RGB):

[image]

But this looks exactly like it's grayscale version. For the above image, when stacking numpy arrays, I cannot make the image look similar to the grayscale one.

Comment: matplotlib **auto-scales the range of values** of your data so all values are within the range of black to white. and since you are demanding `cmap='gray'` you aren't even seeing the colors you tried to construct

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want the intensities similar to the one plotted by matplotlib. Re-scaling the intensities results in a ridiculous image. This problem looks specific to numpy arrays, after we are stacking them. Could you please provide a solution to the above problem? i.e., I need a 3 channel image with the same intensity as the one plotted by the epi_img_data variable via matplotlib in the above example.

Comment: As ChristophRackwitz, mentions, when using scalar values, matplotlib maps the lowest value encountered to black and the highest to white.   When you create rgb-values, you get what you want: precise values for red, green and blue.  Note that the `cmap`  is ignored in that case. If you want a similar result as with scalar values, you need to subtract the minimum, divide by the new maximum, multiply by 255 and only then stack the values together. The simplest solution is to stick with the scalar values and forget about stacking and creating rgb values.

Comment: @JohanC Normalizing doesn't help for this particular problem. The minimum is 0 for this particular image. Dividing by maximum and rescaling it up results in a bad image. The code is self contained to reproduce the error in google colab, and I am unable to get exactly what I want, even after rescaling. Could you solve the problem by giving exact code for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you scale it as Cristolph and Johan described, the 3-channel plot becomes identical:

```py
epi_img_data -= epi_img_data.min()
epi_img_data /= epi_img_data.max()
total_mask = np.stack((epi_img_data,)*3, axis=-1)

plt.imshow(total_mask)
```

[image: 1- vs 3-channel]

Comment: Note that if you have many similar images, you'd want to extract and divide the same overall min/max for each of them.